# Change the theme of Donut chart using JqPlot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

The main goal of my issue is to put specific colors on Donut Change.
I googled for a while and I thinks that JqPlot is the best library for this, but I'm facing problems trying to change the theme of donut chart on JqPlot:

I found the documentation here:

http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/theming.html

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-themeEngine-js.html

So I tried apply theme like this:

```
var gabe = {
    seriesColors: ["#4bb2c5", "#EAA228", "#c5b47f", "#579575", "#839557", "#958c12"],
    grid: { backgroundColor: '#000000' }
}
... {my chart}
plot3.themeEngine.newTheme('gabe', gabe);
plot3.activateTheme('gabe');
```

But only the background changed. How can I change the donut colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not placing the `seriesColors` in `seriesStyles`. The below code is taken from the first link you have provided :)

```
    gabe = {
        seriesStyles: {
            seriesColors: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo'],
            highlightColors: ['lightpink', 'lightsalmon', 'lightyellow', 'lightgreen', 'lightblue', 'mediumslateblue']
        },
        legend: {
            fontSize: '8pt'
        },
        title: {
            fontSize: '18pt'
        },
        grid: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(211, 233, 195)'
        }
    };
    plot.themeEngine.newTheme('gabe', gabe);
    plot.activateTheme('gabe');
```

[This is what it does.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/NYewy/42/)

[This sample shows that all gets applied just not](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/NYewy/43/) the `seriesColors` (as we commented out the `seriesStyles` for this one). Thus, conclusion that `seriesColors` must be placed inside the `seriesStyles`.

I did this analysys as it was my first contact with the theme feature of `jqPlot` and by the first look all seemed OK in the code snippet you gave.

Comment: Exactly! There is just one lame part: To create a better looking chart I was forced to manually define a little whiter highlight color for each series color: `var theme = {
            seriesStyles: {
                seriesColors: ['#B97A57', '#FFC90E', '#FF7F27', '#800000'],
                highlightColors: ['#E5976E', '#FFD756', '#FF9E5E', '#B70000']
            }
        };`