# jqplot animation not working for donut charts

Tags: animation, charts, jqplot, donut-chart

I am able to show animations for bar charts and line charts.
Using:

```
animate: true,
animateReplot: true
```

But the animations doesn't seem to work for donut charts.
Can anyone explain me why?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge currently jqplot not support Pie and donut chart animation.It would be nice if jqplot support Pie and donut animation.

We can Change the theme of Donut chart using JqPlot by **seriesStyles** property

```
seriesStyles: {
            seriesColors: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo'],
            highlightColors: ['lightpink', 'lightsalmon', 'lightyellow', 'lightgreen', 'lightblue', 'mediumslateblue']
        }
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/NYewy/42/) from [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228308/change-the-theme-of-donut-chart-using-jqplot)

Comment: Yeah I think you are right. but there should be some way to implement it. : (